# How to get .unique() for timedelta64 column to show time in days?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a `duration` column of type `timedelta64[ns]` that shows the time duration in days:

[image]

I want to get all the unique values from `duration`, but this is what I get instead:

```
array([5011200000000000, 5184000000000000, 3888000000000000,
       2592000000000000, 4838400000000000, 2937600000000000,
       1641600000000000, 3801600000000000, 2505600000000000,
       2332800000000000, 1209600000000000, 3024000000000000,
       3456000000000000,  864000000000000, 2160000000000000,
       4147200000000000, 2073600000000000, 3542400000000000,
       5097600000000000, 3628800000000000, 4492800000000000,
       2851200000000000, 1814400000000000, 1468800000000000,
       3974400000000000, 3369600000000000, 2678400000000000,
       5702400000000000, 4233600000000000, 3196800000000000,
       2419200000000000, 3110400000000000, 1555200000000000,
       1123200000000000,  345600000000000, 2764800000000000,
       4752000000000000, 4320000000000000, 2246400000000000,
       1987200000000000, 4406400000000000, 1296000000000000,
       1728000000000000, 7430400000000000, 1900800000000000,
       3283200000000000, 3715200000000000, 1036800000000000,
        950400000000000,  777600000000000, 7084800000000000,
        604800000000000, 4579200000000000, 7776000000000000,
        518400000000000, 6134400000000000,  432000000000000,
        691200000000000, 5270400000000000,                0,
       1382400000000000,   86400000000000, 4060800000000000,
       7689600000000000, 4665600000000000, 6220800000000000,
       4924800000000000, 5529600000000000, 7171200000000000,
       5356800000000000,  259200000000000, 5616000000000000,
       7862400000000000, 5961600000000000, 5875200000000000,
       7257600000000000, 5788800000000000, 6048000000000000,
       6307200000000000, 7516800000000000, 6912000000000000,
       7603200000000000,  172800000000000, 6393600000000000,
       6566400000000000, 6480000000000000, 6825600000000000,
       5443200000000000, 7344000000000000, 6739200000000000,
       6652800000000000, 6998400000000000, 7948800000000000],
      dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

Which I believe is the equivalent time in milliseconds? How do I get `.unique()` return what it shows in the column, i.e. in days?

Comment: Could you make this reproducible by providing some sample data? Have you tried calling [`pandas.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) on the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique` returns numpy.ndarray. Numpy represents timedelta as nanoseconds as you see in your output. Assume your `duration` has only days, you may overcome this by use `dt.days` and add string `days` before `unique`

```
Sample `df`:

  duration
0  58 days
1  60 days
2  45 days
3  30 days
4  56 days

(df['duration'].dt.days.astype(str) + ' days').unique()

Out[126]:
array(['58 days', '60 days', '45 days', '30 days', '56 days'],
      dtype=object)
```

---

If you want numpy still keeps dtype as `timedelta`, you may cast `unique` to `timedelta[D]`

```
df['duration'].unique().astype('timedelta64[D]')

Out[129]: array([58, 60, 45, 30, 56], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```